# Debugging a AngularJS + Spring MVC + Tomcat web application

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

My days of Java web development now lie about 6 years behind me and despite my hectic new life as a non-technical consultant I want to get back in to the tech world and equip myself with some essential web dev skills.

To get me started, I installed a vagrant box using this tutorial:
https://dzone.com/articles/vagrant

... which worked like a treat and got me my Ubuntu box on my Windows host machine up and running in no time. Also it comes with Java 7 and the Tomcat app server that I'm still quite familiar with from past days. Notwithstanding the fact that there are probably better servers out there to practice on, this one works and I'll use it for my tinkering for now. The example web app that came with the tutorial also works, so I'm confident that my Tomcat is running on the guest machine on port 8080.

The next step was to find a good AngularJS and Spring MVC tutorial. Again, while I know that AngularJS is the latest craze in web dev, Spring MVC may be somewhat outdated (?) but since I'm a Java-boy since I hatched from the Uni-egg I wouldn't mind going with it for now.

The tutorial I found is this one:
http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-angularjs-example/

I downloaded the project from git and deployed it into my tomcat webapps folder. In the user_service.js file I left the REST_SERVICE_URI as http://localhost:8080/Spring4MVCAngularJSExample/user/ given that Tomcat runs on port 8080 on the host Ubuntu box and I can access the application on my guest machine in the browser at http://192.168.33.10:8080/Spring4MVCAngularJSExample

The problem is that the application (while it's showing up in the browser), does not load the mock-users that are populated in the UserServiceImpl class and that should show up when loading the app. When I check my Firefox console under the JavaScript tab, I get the 'Error while fetching Users' error message from the fetchAllUsers function in the user_controller.js script.

I suspect that the problem here is that the front-end (AngularJS $http service) cannot contact the back-end (Spring service). If there were no users in the back-end and returned 0, I wouldn't get the error but an empty set instead, hence my suspicion of some other problem.

My question is how to debug this web app from here? I have tried to look through the front-end console logs using the FF Developer tool (Debugger) and I must admit I haven't written any JUnit test to actually run a test against the Spring service implementation class.

Thanks for your advice, and let me know if I should provide any more details.

Cheers
AHL

Spring controller:

```
    package com.websystique.springmvc.controller;

    import java.util.List;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;

    import com.websystique.springmvc.model.User;
    import com.websystique.springmvc.service.UserService;

    @RestController
    public class HelloWorldRestController {

        @Autowired
        UserService userService;  //Service which will do all data retrieval/manipulation work


        //-------------------Retrieve All Users--------------------------------------------------------

        @RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ResponseEntity<List<User>> listAllUsers() {
            List<User> users = userService.findAllUsers();
            if(users.isEmpty()){
                return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);//You many decide to return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
        }



        //-------------------Retrieve Single User--------------------------------------------------------

        @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
            System.out.println("Fetching User with id " + id);
            User user = userService.findById(id);
            if (user == null) {
                System.out.println("User with id " + id + " not found");
                return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
        }



        //-------------------Create a User--------------------------------------------------------

        @RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ResponseEntity<Void> createUser(@RequestBody User user,    UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {
            System.out.println("Creating User " + user.getUsername());

            if (userService.isUserExist(user)) {
                System.out.println("A User with name " + user.getUsername() + " already exist");
                return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
            }

            userService.saveUser(user);

            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/user/{id}").buildAndExpand(user.getId()).toUri());
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }



        //------------------- Update a User --------------------------------------------------------

        @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
        public ResponseEntity<User> updateUser(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestBody User user) {
            System.out.println("Updating User " + id);

            User currentUser = userService.findById(id);

            if (currentUser==null) {
                System.out.println("User with id " + id + " not found");
                return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            }

            currentUser.setUsername(user.getUsername());
            currentUser.setAddress(user.getAddress());
            currentUser.setEmail(user.getEmail());

            userService.updateUser(currentUser);
            return new ResponseEntity<User>(currentUser, HttpStatus.OK);
        }



        //------------------- Delete a User --------------------------------------------------------

        @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
        public ResponseEntity<User> deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
            System.out.println("Fetching & Deleting User with id " + id);

            User user = userService.findById(id);
            if (user == null) {
                System.out.println("Unable to delete. User with id " + id + " not found");
                return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            }

            userService.deleteUserById(id);
            return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }



        //------------------- Delete All Users --------------------------------------------------------

        @RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
        public ResponseEntity<User> deleteAllUsers() {
            System.out.println("Deleting All Users");

            userService.deleteAllUsers();
            return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }

    }
```

IndexController.java:

```
package com.websystique.springmvc.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class IndexController {

      @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String getIndexPage() {
            return "UserManagement";
        }

}
```

Javascript user_controller.js:

```
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp').controller('UserController', ['$scope', 'UserService', function($scope, UserService) {
        var self = this;
        self.user={id:null,username:'',address:'',email:''};
        self.users=[];

        self.submit = submit;
        self.edit = edit;
        self.remove = remove;
        self.reset = reset;


        fetchAllUsers();

        function fetchAllUsers(){
            UserService.fetchAllUsers()
                .then(
                function(d) {
                    self.users = d;
                },
                function(errResponse){
                    console.error('Error while fetching Users');
                }
            );
        }

        function createUser(user){
            UserService.createUser(user)
                .then(
                fetchAllUsers,
                function(errResponse){
                    console.error('Error while creating User');
                }
            );
        }

        function updateUser(user, id){
            UserService.updateUser(user, id)
                .then(
                fetchAllUsers,
                function(errResponse){
                    console.error('Error while updating User');
                }
            );
        }

        function deleteUser(id){
            UserService.deleteUser(id)
                .then(
                fetchAllUsers,
                function(errResponse){
                    console.error('Error while deleting User');
                }
            );
        }

        function submit() {
            if(self.user.id===null){
                console.log('Saving New User', self.user);
                createUser(self.user);
            }else{
                updateUser(self.user, self.user.id);
                console.log('User updated with id ', self.user.id);
            }
            reset();
        }

        function edit(id){
            console.log('id to be edited', id);
            for(var i = 0; i < self.users.length; i++){
                if(self.users[i].id === id) {
                    self.user = angular.copy(self.users[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        function remove(id){
            console.log('id to be deleted', id);
            if(self.user.id === id) {//clean form if the user to be deleted is shown there.
                reset();
            }
            deleteUser(id);
        }


        function reset(){
            self.user={id:null,username:'',address:'',email:''};
            $scope.myForm.$setPristine(); //reset Form
        }

    }]);
```

Javascript user_service.js:

```
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp').factory('UserService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){

        var REST_SERVICE_URI = 'http://localhost:8080/Spring4MVCAngularJSExample/user/';

        var factory = {
            fetchAllUsers: fetchAllUsers,
            createUser: createUser,
            updateUser:updateUser,
            deleteUser:deleteUser
        };

        return factory;

        function fetchAllUsers() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get(REST_SERVICE_URI)
                .then(
                function (response) {
                    deferred.resolve(response.data);
                },
                function(errResponse){
                    console.error('Error while fetching Users');
                    deferred.reject(errResponse);
                }
            );
            return deferred.promise;
        }

        function createUser(user) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.post(REST_SERVICE_URI, user)
                .then(
                function (response) {
                    deferred.resolve(response.data);
                },
                function(errResponse){
                    console.error('Error while creating User');
                    deferred.reject(errResponse);
                }
            );
            return deferred.promise;
        }


        function updateUser(user, id) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.put(REST_SERVICE_URI+id, user)
                .then(
                function (response) {
                    deferred.resolve(response.data);
                },
                function(errResponse){
                    console.error('Error while updating User');
                    deferred.reject(errResponse);
                }
            );
            return deferred.promise;
        }

        function deleteUser(id) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.delete(REST_SERVICE_URI+id)
                .then(
                function (response) {
                    deferred.resolve(response.data);
                },
                function(errResponse){
                    console.error('Error while deleting User');
                    deferred.reject(errResponse);
                }
            );
            return deferred.promise;
        }

    }]);
```

On the server (the vagrant host machine), I can wget the URL and get my data back from the Spring server:

```
    vagrant@precise32:~$ wget http://localhost:8080/Spring4MVCAngularJSExample/user/--2016-08-26 11:08:24--  http://localhost:8080/Spring4MVCAngularJSExample/user/
    Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
    Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8080... connected.
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
    Length: unspecified [application/json]
    Saving to: `index.html'

        [ <=>                                   ] 206         --.-K/s   in 0s

    2016-08-26 11:08:24 (9.77 MB/s) - `index.html' saved [206]

    vagrant@precise32:~$ less index.html
```

this gives me the expected result set:

```
[{"id":1,"username":"Sam","address":"NY","email":"sam@abc.com"},{"id":2,"username":"Tomy","address":"ALBAMA","email":"tomy@abc.com"},{"id":3,"username":"Kelly","address":"NEBRASKA","email":"kelly@abc.com"}]
```

Comment: Did you say you tried http://192.168.33.10:8080/Spring4MVCAngularJSExample/user directly in your browser?

Comment: No, I accessed the web app through the address 192.168.33.10:8080/Spring4MVCAngularJSExample/. From what I understand though, the javascript service calls 192.168.33.10:8080/Spring4MVCAngularJSExample/user/ as this is the address for the spring service. This is how it was suggested in the tutorial. Should I try to call 192.168.33.10:8080/Spring4MVCAngularJSExample/user/ and see if the browser can contact the spring service that way?

Comment: Yes, the angular app is just a way to display what your rest service returns. You should get the raw data from that /user url or get an error. This way you will know if the problem comes from angular or java.

Comment: Thanks bud - I will test this when I get back home. I suppose I can also test parameters for the service by passing them in via the url? F.ex. .../user/[id], where [id] is an actual number of a record that exists. Cheers.

Comment: I get a 404: HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource () is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.26

Comment: In my catalina.out log I get: Aug 26, 2016 10:40:58 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Spring4MVCAngularJSExample/user] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Comment: In my code I have this in my Spring Controller class: "@RestController
public class HelloWorldRestController {" ... and also this: "@RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> listAllUsers() {"

Comment: Ok, so the problem was that I didn't add the "/" to the end of my URL. When I call http://192.168.33.10:8080/Spring4MVCAngularJSExample/user/ in the browser I actually get a result set now. But, when calling http://192.168.33.10:8080/Spring4MVCAngularJSExample, i.e. the main web-app, the front-end never reaches the back-end, as there is no log created in my catalina.out. I think the problem is with the front-end. I have apended the JS controller code in my original post. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

From your spring controller code all your request mappings are expecting user in the url so if you don't have this the spring controllers will not be called. Is you dispatcher servlet set up to except all http requests E.g /

Comment: not quite sure ... I dont use a dispatcher servlet, but I have a IndexController file, which I have included in the original post.

Comment: You can download firebug which is a Firefox addon. Then you can open up the user service has file and put a break point at the fetchallusers. You should be able to inspect errors from here which might help

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a simple mistake:

In the user_service.js file, the REST_SERVICE_URI must be set to the address of the host machine:

http://192.168.33.10:8080/Spring4MVCAngularJSExample/user/

So, when deploying this to a (remote) server, I suppose the 192.168.33.10:8080 portion would need to be changed to that server's IP and the respective Tomcat port.

My problem existed (probably) because I was using a virtual box and had (mistakenly) used the host machine's IP instead of the guest machine's IP. Please correct me if I'm wrong, I'm still somewhat confused ....